# Handling update failure in Play 2.5 and ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have written simple rest API that will add music track data to mongodb.

I am able to write track successfully, however I would like to handle error case.

My code as below  -

```
  def saveTrack = Action.async(parse.json) { 
     import model.Track.trackFormat
     implicit request =>
    request.body.validate[Track].map { data =>
      trackService.save(data).onComplete {
        case Success(value) => Ok(Json.obj("message" -> Messages("track.save.ack")))
        case Failure(e) => Ok(Json.obj("message" -> Messages("track.save.nack")))
    }
    }
    Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj("message" -> Messages("track.save.fin"))))
  }
```

Lets suppose there is some failure happen in trackService.save(data) then I want to return error code. I am wondering how to achieve that.

Thanks
Pari

Comment: You can return an error code in `case Failure` no ?

Comment: Either it is success or failure it executes only 
Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj("message" -> Messages("track.save.fin"))))

Comment: and you want to execute `Ok(Json.obj("message" -> Messages("track.save.nack")))`  in case of failure? Right ?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def saveTrack = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    request
      .body
      .validate[Track]
      .map { data =>
        trackService.save(data).map { v =>
          Ok(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> Messages("ack"))))
        }.recover {
          case _ =>
            Ok(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> Messages("nack"))))
        }
      }.getOrElse {Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> "bad json")))
    }
  }
```

Use `recover` to handle errors and `getOrElse` in case the json body is not matching your model.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. I just had to change - }.getOrElse { Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> "bad json"))) }